# How to expand the "Y" scale of the data in chart.js?

Tags: chart.js

How to expand the "Y" scale of the data to lookes more beautiful? The bar data is cut off by the top border of the graph. If the maximum number is 100, then display, for example, 110, that would be a small padding from the top border.

My code: https://jsfiddle.net/selvestrstal/ent8zchq/

```
var data = {
   labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
   datasets: [{
      label: "First dataset",
      data: [65, 100, 100, 81, 56, 55, 90]
   }, {
      label: "Third dataset",
      data: [38, 55, 50, 65, 35, 67, 54]
   }]
}; 

var chart = new Chart('graph_data', {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: true,
        filler: {
            propagate: true
        },
        tooltips: {
            mode: 'index',
            intersect: false,
            callbacks: {
                title: function(i, val) {
                    return [0].xLabel;
                },
            },
        },
        legend: {
           display: true,
        },
        layout: {
            padding: {
                left: 5,
                right: 5,
                top: 5,
                bottom: 10
            }
        },
        scales: {
            padding: 10,
            xAxes: [{
                display: true,
                ticks: {
                    autoSkip: true,
                    offset: true,
                    maxRotation: 0,
                    padding: 5,
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                display: true,
                 ticks: {
                    autoSkip: true,
                    offset: true,
                    maxRotation: 0,
                    beginAtZero: false,
                    padding: 5,
                },
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Override the scale:

Try something like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
        scaleOverride : true,
        scaleSteps : 10,
        scaleStepWidth : 50,
        scaleStartValue : 0 
    });
}
```

A `max` option is also viable, as it helped the author of the question.

Comment: thanks for answer. Nothing happened: https://jsfiddle.net/selvestrstal/ent8zchq/5/

Comment: Try setting scales inside options like this: https://jsfiddle.net/52afmcej/

Comment: Thanks. Now it is working. All I needed was to add a `max:` option. But I do not see it in your answer ...

Comment: just edit your answer please. It is could be usefull for somebody else)